# issue in changing string to number in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a string and i want to change it to  number in javascript.

```
console.log(this.CountModel.get("count"));
var totalPages = parseInt(Math.ceil(this.CountModel.get("count") / numPerPage));
console.log(totalPages);
```

I used parsint but did not work.
The first console return 200 which is right and the next console returns NAN.
But how can I get the totalpages in number?

Thanks

Comment: `this.CountModel.get("count")` is string?

Comment: could you please show us the string you're feeding to parseInt?

Comment: what does :: console.log(this.CountModel.get("count")); return.?

Comment: You're feeding `parseInt()` with the result of a division. How can that be a string?

Comment: Math.ceil(this.CountModel.get("count") / numPerPage) i think this is string. otherwise second console did not return NAN.

Comment: numPerPage is probably a string (or zero) and should be parsed as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should parse the string before you try to calculate with it:

```
var totalPages = Math.ceil(parseInt(this.CountModel.get("count")) / numPerPage);
```

*Assuming `numPerPage` is already an Integer, and not zero (thanks to user1600124)*

Comment: Also make sure that numPerPage is not 0.